# In CSS Grid, my image is overflowing the row for which I've specified a grid-template-row size

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

So I'm using `grid` for the group of images on the left side of the `product`. The problem I'm having is when I try to set `grid-template-rows`, the image overflows the grid cell.

When I use the inspector tool, the grid shows the row height was properly implemented so I tried using `overflow: hidden` on the `product__image` element. However, the `border-radius` for the bottom part of the first image disappears.

Is there a way I can resize the largest image and keep applying the `border-radius` property?

```
.product {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 9rem;
  column-gap: 12rem;

  &__wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 44.5rem auto;
    grid-template-areas:
      "main main main main"
      "sub1 sub2 sub3 sub4";
    gap: 3.2rem 3rem;
  }

  &__left,
  &__right {
    width: 50%;
  }

  &__image {
    object-fit: cover;

    & img {
      border-radius: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    &-1 {
      grid-area: main;
    }

    &-2 {
      grid-area: sub1;
    }

    &-3 {
      grid-area: sub2;
    }

    &-4 {
      grid-area: sub3;
    }

    &-5 {
      grid-area: sub4;
    }
  }

  &__right {
    // display: flex;
    // flex-direction: column;
  }

  &__copy {
    font-size: 1.2rem;

    &--company {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: $primary-orange;
      margin-bottom: 2.8rem;
    }
    &--edition {
      font-size: 3.2rem;
      margin-bottom: 4.8rem;
    }
  }

  &__pricing {
    font-size: 2.1rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    &--disc,
    &--old {
      font-size: 1.4rem;
    }

    &--old {
      display: block;
    }
  }

  &__options {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="container product">
      <div class="product__left">
        <div class="product__wrapper">
          <div class="product__image product__image-1">
            <img src="./assets/images/image-product-1.jpg" alt="Sneakers Image" class="product__image-item" />
          </div>
          <div class="product__image product__image-2">
            <img src="./assets/images/image-product-2-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Sneakers Image" class="product__image-item" />
          </div>
          <div class="product__image product__image-3">
            <img src="./assets/images/image-product-3-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Sneakers Image" class="product__image-item" />
          </div>
          <div class="product__image product__image-4">
            <img src="./assets/images/image-product-4-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Sneakers Image" class="product__image-item" />
          </div>
          <div class="product__image product__image-5">
            <img src="./assets/images/image-product-1-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Sneakers Image" class="product__image-item" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product__right">
        <div class="product__copy">
          <h3 class="product__copy--company">Sneaker Company</h3>
          <h2 class="product__copy--edition">Fall Limited Edition Sneakers</h2>
          <p class="product__copy--desc"
            >These low-profile sneakers are your perfect casual wear companion. Featuring a durable rubber outer sole, they'll withstand everything the weather can offer.</p
          >
        </div>
        <div class="product__pricing">
          <h4 class="product__pricing--new">$125.00</h4>
          <h5 class="product__pricing--disc">50%</h5>
        </div>
        <small class="product__pricing--old">$250.00</small>
        <div class="product__options">
          <div class="product__counter">0</div>
          <div class="product__cart">
            <svg width="22" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path
                d="M20.925 3.641H3.863L3.61.816A.896.896 0 0 0 2.717 0H.897a.896.896 0 1 0 0 1.792h1l1.031 11.483c.073.828.52 1.726 1.291 2.336C2.83 17.385 4.099 20 6.359 20c1.875 0 3.197-1.87 2.554-3.642h4.905c-.642 1.77.677 3.642 2.555 3.642a2.72 2.72 0 0 0 2.717-2.717 2.72 2.72 0 0 0-2.717-2.717H6.365c-.681 0-1.274-.41-1.53-1.009l14.321-.842a.896.896 0 0 0 .817-.677l1.821-7.283a.897.897 0 0 0-.87-1.114ZM6.358 18.208a.926.926 0 0 1 0-1.85.926.926 0 0 1 0 1.85Zm10.015 0a.926.926 0 0 1 0-1.85.926.926 0 0 1 0 1.85Zm2.021-7.243-13.8.81-.57-6.341h15.753l-1.383 5.53Z"
                fill="#69707D"
                fill-rule="nonzero"
              />
            </svg>
            <a href="#" class="product__cart--add">Add to cart</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Could you put some images in that we can use? It helps especially since the question refers to a large image and we don't know what that is.

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth Added a codepen here [link](https://codepen.io/jecrram/pen/qBXRabq)

Comment: The codepen shows the image with rounded bottom corners - should there be a longer image in there?